# How to deploy the war file automatcally in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, svn, ant

My requirement is to download the war file from svn and deploy that war file into tomcat in everyday.I have prepared the ant script for this issue.In ant script i can able to get the war but i struggled how to deploy that war in daily basis.

Comment: I think it depends on tomcat's version, but in tomcat 5.X and 6, just copy war file in `webapps` directory under tomcat installation. Not sure on newer versions

Comment: It'll work as well under tomcat 7: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup, and Tomcat 8: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup

Comment: you can go with jenkins rit? https://jenkins-ci.org/

Comment: you can use crontab. set up a cron expression to run for the required time.

Comment: question is very broad.  What is the version of tomcat? What have you tried so far?  Here is one way : http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/AntDeploy

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins to build and deploy your web apps. it is very easy and open source. down load it [here](https://jenkins-ci.org/). configure a maven job . there you have an option poll scm you can schedule your build there.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get already your WAR, deploying it to tomcat7/webapps dir 
and setting tomcat7 conf (tomcat/conf/server.xml) like will automaticly deploy your war.

```js
   <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```